# Salvar saída de consulta a JSON e contar os resultados

Tags: python, json

Tenho um JSON com a seguinte estrutura (não posso mudar a estrutura do JSON pois é usado por outro *script*):

```
[
  {
    "Latitude":"-22.1156051",
    "Status":"1",
    "Id":1,
    "Longitude":"-43.2100901",
    "Descricao":"TRR - AG TRES RIOS"
  },
  {
    "Latitude":"-22.1156051",
    "Status":"0",
    "Id":2,
    "Longitude":"-43.2100901",
    "Descricao":"SAQ - AG  SAQUAREMA"
  },
  {
    "Latitude":"-22.1156051",
    "Status":"1",
    "Id":1,
    "Longitude":"-43.2100901",
    "Descricao":"BHE - AG BELO HORIZONTE"
  }
]
```

Meu Script é:

```
import json
f = open("test.json", "r")
data = f.read()
jsondata = json.loads(data)

for agencias in jsondata:
    if agencias["Status"] == "2":
        print(agencias["Descricao"])
```

Preciso salvar um TXT que contenha o número de localidades que o `Status = 2` e `Descrição` das 4 primeiras localidades.

Exemplo:

```
2 
BHE - AG BELO HORIZONTE
TRR - AG TRES RIOS
```

E, caso a consulta não retorne um valor, preciso que a saída no arquivo de texto seja:

```
Nenhuma Agencia Indisponível.
```

Comment: Certo, mas o que você tentou fazer e qual foi a dificuldade? O que sabe de Python? Leia sobre o módulo [`json`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) do Python.

Comment: tentei começar por aqui: #!/usr/bin/python3
import json

with open("/js/pontos2.js")

print(json.count("Status"))

Comment: Anael, veja se a pergunta citada não te ajuda. Se não, peço que edite a pergunta a adicionando maiores detalhes do que fez e qual foi a dificuldade encontrada. Toda e qualquer informação referente à pergunta deve estar na pergunta, não use os comentários para isso.

Comment: Anderson, a minha diciculdade é pra conseguir consultar os dados e gerar o TXT.

Comment: Sobre consultar os dados a partir do JSON já foi discutido na pergunta citada. Quanto a gerar o arquivo TXT, também há várias perguntas na comunidade que pode consultar. Então manterei a posição em que recomendo que você edite a pergunta, descreva melhor o que fez e qual foi o resultado obtido. Se for coerente, poderemos reabrir a pergunta.

Comment: import json
f = open("test.json", "r")
data = f.read()
jsondata = json.loads(data)

print jsondata 

     consigo imprimir todo o meu json, mais queria que aparecem dados especificos como somente quantos registros estão com o ID =1

Comment: Anderson você pode rever a minha pergunta por favor.

Comment: A saída do `print` é a desejada ou ela apresenta dados errados? E sobre criar o arquivo, você chegou a pesquisar sobre? Viu a função [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open)? Poderia adicionar na pergunta também essa parte do seu código?

Comment: Anderson a saída do print é o resultado desejado